# Workbook.Protect bug with toggling protection

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet-protection

When I call Thisworkbook.Protect in VBA the protection of the workbook actually **toggles** from the current workbook's protection status instead of just protecting the workbook.

Thisworkbook.Unprotect doesn't do this though.

Anyone know why this is the case or how to get around it?

Comment: I've never noticed that. It's true in Excel 2016 on my computer. You could test using `If Thisworkbook.ProtectStructure` or `If Thisworkbook.ProtectWindows`. Also, have you looked at `UserInterfaceOnly`, which can eliminate the necessity to Protect and Unprotect in code?

Comment: UserInterfaceOnly doesn't work for me as I have some code that modifies things that still requires unprotection.  I did a little research and this seems to be a known issue.

Checking the Protection status does work though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it is by design or a bug... If you provide the parameters, it works fine:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Protect ,true,true
```

or

```
ActiveWorkbook.Protect Structure:= true
```

Whichever you need/want. This way it won't turn the protection off, only on.

To turn the protection off, you can use this (assumning you only turned on structure protection):

```
ActiveWorkbook.Protect Structure:= false
```

---

Parameters are:

```
.Protect(Password, Structure, Windows)
```